# View Waypoints in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, gpx, point-of-interest, navigation

I have a GPX file with my waypoints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.0">
    <name>My Favorites</name>
    <wpt lat="-26.7183013" lon="-54.8139346">
        <ele>1</ele>
        <name>F1</name>
    </wpt>
    <wpt lat="-26.7099827" lon="-54.8201895">
        <ele>2</ele>
        <name>F2</name>
    </wpt>
    <wpt lat="-26.6907555" lon="-54.8205221">
        <ele>3</ele>
        <name>F3</name>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Now I want to display them on the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) map.

How can I do this?

I can only drag the file on thr website when in edit mode and even then I do not see them.

<sub>Related: [osm-personal-points-of-interest](https://superuser.com/questions/630288/)</sub>

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Track_drawing_websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you understand German, you can use my Openlayers solution to display GPX tracks and waypoints on top of OSM or other tiles:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Ajoessen/Osmviewer_und_GPXviewer

**EDIT**

Removed the files since they don't work anymore with modern browsers.

Comment: I tried it but it did not show anything. Surely I am doing something wrong since I have no idea about all that. I downloaded the GPXViewer and run my modified GPXCopy.bat, but nothing happened. Is my GPX in the correct format.

Comment: There is a track.gpx of mine in the zip which should appear when you run gpxviewer.htm. Javascript should be enabled. Firefox and most other browsers have a error console which should tell you why the js code does not run as expected. Your GPX data works for me.

Comment: Did not work in Chrome, but does in Firefox. I also had to rename my GPX file to `track.gpx`.

Comment: Can I easily make it display all the names of my waypoints in the map? I can only see the point without any name. Only if I click on it a bulb appears.

Comment: The renaming should have done by the GPXCopy.bat. For the labelling: I did not want that, the map would be overcrowded with labels. But you can have that with Viking, QGIS and QLandkarte GT.

Comment: Unfortunately the linked site is no more.  archive.org has the text, but the important bits are the downloads, and those links are broken too

Comment: The files did not work for me anymore with modern browsers due to security restrictions. I use GPXsee now: http://www.gpxsee.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [uMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/).

It will let you upload a GPX file of waypoints, and can display them on a range of OSM based maps. You can then share this map, or embed it on your website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I especially do **not** want to share the map online.