# OSM personal points of interest

Tags: openstreetmap, gpx, point-of-interest, navigation

I use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) along with [OSMand](http://osmand.net/) on my mobile device.

I have **personal** points of interest on my map that I do not want to upload to the community. Currently I use Favorites in [OSMand](http://osmand.net/) to save them.

Now I want to make a print of that map with my Favorites. How can I bring my Favorites to be displayed in [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) on my PC?

<sub>Related [view-waypoints-in-osm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68363/)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install QGIS 1.8.0, and the Openlayers plugin which serves you with an Openstreetmap background.

You can import your data as text delimited layer, or GPX points layer, and print them on top of the Openstreetmap background.

If your data is in lat/long degrees, the Coordinate system for your **layer** should be `EPSG:4326` WGS 84. The **project** CRS has to be `EPSG:3857` Google Mercator. With "On-the-fly-projection" activated in `Settings->Project Settings`, both layers should align.

---

The open-source software viking http://sourceforge.net/projects/viking/ does a similar job, maybe easier for a newbie. QLandkarte GT http://www.qlandkarte.org/ is similar to it.

Comment: *Viking* works for me. Awesome!